# Identify last linux shutdown time

Tags: shutdown, power, logging, redhat-enterprise-linux

We have a server running *RHEL 5*.

Sometimes the power cuts and the server is down (the UPS handles only 30 min).

I want to be able to to identify the time of the shutdown, in an other term the last minute where the server was up.

I tried `last` command but it only logs shutdown started by a command.

I also checked the `/var/log/messages` but I don't see anything useful for my question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following command

```
last -1x shutdown
```

or the reboot could be helpful in this situation

```
last reboot | less
```

Comment: `last -1x shutdown` is exactly what I need. Thanks! For anyone interested in the output:
```
❯ last -1x shutdown
shutdown system down  5.15.38-1-MANJAR Mon May 23 22:21 - 06:50  (08:29)
```
Here's the flag meaning:
```
 -x, --system
     Display the system shutdown entries and run level changes.
```